# Is there a way to order your projects by date in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

I am new to NetBeans & stackoverflow.
Is there maybe a way to order your projects by date and not in alphabetical order?
I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no way to display your projects ordered by date in NetBeans. They are always displayed in alphabetic order, and there is no functionality that would allow the projects to be arbitrarily reordered using drag and drop. However, there are a couple of approaches that might be helpful:

**Use Project Groups**

NetBeans has the concept of a **Project Group** which can be associated with zero or more projects, (similar to a **Working Set** in Eclipse). For example, you could place projects created this month in a project group named **1801**, projects created last month in a project group named **1712**, etc.

Then you could display only the projects within a specific project group, although within that group the projects would still be listed in alphabetic order. Also, a project can belong to multiple groups.

The formal documentation from Oracle is here: [How to Organize Projects into Groups](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG2209). Since you are new to NetBeans this very basic video may also be helpful: [Netbeans Tutorial Part 8: How do you Create a Project Group using netbeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkbZ5o8oG8g)

**Use semantic naming for your projects**

An alternative approach that is very crude but highly effective would be to simply prefix each project name with the date it was created. For example, name a project created today as **180116MyWebApp** instead of **MyWebApp**). When NetBeans lists your projects they will still be in in alphabetic order, but also in ascending date order.

If that approach is viable it would be trivial to safely rename your existing projects within NetBeans: just select the project node in the **Projects** pane, right-click and select **Rename...** from the popup menu.

Comment: I'll definitely make use of the project groups now that I know NetBeans has got this. This was very helpfull, thanks!